# Can I hook this code up to deploy solution(Creating User groups in Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2010

I am wondering is it possible to create user groups on the fly when you hit deploy in Visual Studios 2010?

I found  [this tutorial](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/09/03/programmatically-create-user-groups-sharepoint-2010/)  on how to make a user group but I would be unsure how to run this code on deploy.

If someone knows other-ways to achieve this let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to create a feature, then add a feature event receiver to the feature.  You can then run code when the feature is activated.

For more information, there's a good tutorial here: (updated link for SP 2010)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231604.aspx

Comment: Cool. However do you something like this in sharepoint 2010? I finding it hard to follow some parts as I think there using sharepoint 2007. For instance I can't find the WSP View or features.xml(Step 8)

Comment: Try this link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231604.aspx.  I didn't notice the version in the tags when I searched for the link, sorry.  The process is very similar, but the tools differ between the two versions.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a console application and run this code from there. Application must run on the server.